# SQL query needed - Counting 365 days backwards

Tags: sql, oracle

I have searched the forum many times but couldn't find a solution for my situation. I am working with an Oracle database.

I have a table with all Order Numbers and Customer Numbers by Day. It looks like this:

```
Day | Customer Nbr | Order Nbr  
2018-01-05 | 25687459 | 256   
2018-01-09 | 36478592 | 398  
2018-03-07 | 25687459 | 1547  
and so on....
```

Now I need a SQL Query which gives me a table by day and Customer Nbr and counts the number of unique Order Numbers within the last 365 days starting from column 1.

For the example above the resulting table should look like:

```
Day | Customer Nbr | Order Cnt  
2019-01-01 | 25687459  | 2  
2019-01-02 | 25687459  | 2  
... 
2019-03-01 | 25687459  | 1
```

Comment: can you please add  a bigger dataset for data  and output?

Comment: How is that output "counting backwards"? Shouldn't the first row contain todays date if descending order or today - 1 year if ascending?

Comment: I am very sorry but I don't understand your question. I try to explain in different words. 
The source table has all Order Numbers and Customer Numbers per Day.  

In the resulting table I want to see for every day in the past how many orders every customer has made. But only in a certain timeframe, which is between the day we are looking at and (the day we are lookign at minus 364 days).  

So, lets say Customer A has made 5 orders in 2018.

Comment: I am very sorry but I don't understand your question. I try to explain in different words. 

So, lets say Customer A has made 5 orders in 2018.

I need a table for every day in 2019 (lat's say starting with 2019-01-01). 
First row gives me the amount of orders the customer had made between 2018-01-02 and 2019-01-01 (which is 5)

The second row is 2019-01-02 and gives me the amount of orders the customer has made between 2018-01-03 and 2019-01-02

The third row is 2019-01-03 and gives me the amount of orders the customer has made between 2018-01-04 and 2019-01-03

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**:

I've just seen you clarify the question, which I've interpreted to mean:
For every day in the last year, show how many orders there were for each customer between that date, and 1 year previously. Working on an answer now...

Updated Answer:

For each customer, we count the number of records between the order day, and 365 days before it...

```
WITH yourTable AS
(
  SELECT SYSDATE - 1 Day, 'Alex' CustomerNbr FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT SYSDATE - 2, 'Alex' FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT SYSDATE - 366, 'Alex'FROM DUAL

  UNION ALL
  SELECT SYSDATE - 400, 'Alex'FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT SYSDATE - 500, 'Alex'FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT SYSDATE - 1, 'Joe'FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT SYSDATE - 300, 'Chris'FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT SYSDATE - 1, 'Chris'FROM DUAL
)

SELECT Day, CustomerNbr, OrdersLast365Days
FROM yourTable t
OUTER APPLY
(
  SELECT COUNT(1) OrdersLast365Days
  FROM yourTable t2
  WHERE t.CustomerNbr = t2.CustomerNbr
    AND TRUNC(t2.Day) >= TRUNC(t.Day) - 364
    AND TRUNC(t2.Day) <= TRUNC(t.Day)
)
ORDER BY t.Day DESC, t.CustomerNbr;
```

## [image: Last 365 Days' Orders]

If you want to report on just the days you have orders for, then a simple `WHERE` clause should be enough:

```
SELECT Day, CustomerNbr, COUNT(1) OrderCount
FROM <yourTable>
WHERE TRUNC(DAY) >= TRUNC(SYSDATE -364)
GROUP BY Day, CustomerNbr
ORDER BY Day Desc;
```

If you want to report on every day, you'll need to generate them first. This can be done by a recursive CTE, which you then join to your table:

```
WITH last365Days AS
(
  SELECT TRUNC (SYSDATE - ROWNUM + 1) dt
  FROM DUAL CONNECT BY ROWNUM < 365
)

SELECT d.Day, COALESCE(t.CustomerNbr, 'None') CustomerNbr, SUM(CASE WHEN t.CustomerNbr IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) OrderCount
FROM last365Days d
LEFT OUTER JOIN <yourTable> t
  ON d.Day = TRUNC(t.Day)
GROUP BY d.Day, t.CustomerNbr
ORDER BY d.Day Desc;
```

[image: Left Join CTE]

Comment: Thank you for your response. I don't understand all of it and just try it out. 

What is DUAL? I often get "unsupported column aliasing". Do you know what this could mean?

Comment: No problem. I think the "Unsupported column aliasing" was because I used CTEs (with x (col1, col2) AS....) which doens't work before Oracle 11.2 - I guess you're using an older version?

DUAL is a placeholder table so you can select things without using a real table (SELECT DUMMY FROM DUAL) just returns 'x'. I mainly use it for applying logic to columns in CROSS/OUTER APPLY or CTEs though.

Comment: I've updated the CTEs to use the old way of column aliasing, and the older CONNECT BY statement to generate the 365 days

Answer (score 0):

One method is to generate values for all days of interest for each customer and then use a correlated subquery:

```
with dates as (
      select date '2019-01-01' + rownum as dte from dual
      connect by date '2019-01-01' + rownum < sysdate
     )
select d.dte, t.customer_nbr,
       (select count(*)
        from t t2
        where t2.customer_nbr = t.customer_nbr and
              t2.day <= t.dte and
              t2.date > t.dte - 365
       ) as order_cnt
from dates d cross join
     (select distinct customer_nbr from t) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would probably have done it with and analytic function. In your windowing clause, you can specify a number of rows before, or a range. In this case I will use a range.

This will give you, For Each customer for each day the number of orders during one rolling year before the date displayed

```
WITH DATES AS ( 
  SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE)-(LEVEL-1) AS DAY FROM DUAL CONNECT BY TRUNC(SYSDATE)-(LEVEL-1) >= ( SELECT MIN(TRUNC(DAY)) FROM MY_TABLE )) 
    CROSS JOIN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT CUST_ID FROM MY_TABLE))
SELECT DISTINCT
    DATES.DAY,
    DATES.CUST_ID,
    COUNT(ORDER_ID) OVER (PARTITION BY DATES.CUST_ID ORDER BY DATES.DAY RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL '1' YEAR PRECEDING AND INTERVAL '1' SECOND PRECEDING) 
FROM
  DATES
LEFT JOIN 
  MY_TABLE 
ON DATES.DAY=TRUNC(MY_TABLE.DAY) AND DATES.CUST_ID=MY_TABLE.CUST_ID
ORDER BY DATES.CUST_ID,DATES.DAY;
```